# How to connect to postgresql, without specifying plain-text password, with libpq's pgpass?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

Postgres' C library [libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html) talks about a more secure way to connect to a DB without specifying password in source code.

I was not able to find any examples of how to do it.  How to make my Postgre Server use this file?  Please help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't import it into your *Python* program. The point of `.pgpass` is that it is a regular file subject to the system's file permissions, and the *libpq* driver which libraries such as *psycopg2* use to connect to *Postgres* will look to this file for the password instead of requiring the password to be in the source code or prompting for it.

Also, this is not a server-side file, but a client-side one. So, on a *nix box, you would have a `~/.pgpass` file containing the credentials for the various connections you want to be able to make.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Two main things need to happen in order for *psycopg2* to correctly authenticate via `.pgpass`:

1. Do *not* specify a password in the string passed to `psycopg2.connect`
2. Make sure the correct entry is added to the `.pgpass` file for the user who will be connecting via *psycopg2*.

For example, to make this work for all databases for a particular user on **localhost** port **5432**, you would add the following line to that user's `.pgpass` file:

```
localhost:5432:*:<username>:<password>
```

And then the `connect` call would be of this form:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=<dbname> user=<username>")
```

The underlying *libpq* driver that *psycopg2* uses will then utilize the `.pgpass` file to get the password.

Comment: But how psycopg2 connection in python program should looks like to make it look into ~/.pgpass file?

Comment: I simply need to add, that if you are going to this on your *nix box, you must also run the command `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will be ignored. Running this command along with khampson's answer was the solution for me.

Comment: and what if the file is not in a default location? `passfile` does not seem to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

just adding to @khampson's answer,  I could only get this to work (in windows) if I added the PGPASSFILE environment variable (and subsequently restart pycharm) even though my pgpass file is in the default location (%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf).

Answer (score -1):

As explained in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-pgpass.html
.pgpass is a file where every lines contain the sequence

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

It is usually read by libpq based applications.
Substitute the terms with the corresponding values (but the symbol * matches anything in the corresponding field):

```
myserver.example.com:5432:mydatabase:myusername:mypassword
```

A line in the file is then selected depending on the connection parameters used by the application.

If applicable on your OS, to avoid a common mistake remember to grant and limit access to the file only to the effective user running the application.

---

Having used postgresql for decades, I think you might be interested in "The Connection Service File" which seems like *a more current alternative not only to keep the password confidential*.

By default, the per-user service file is named ~/.pg_service.conf.
A different file name can be specified by setting the environment variable PGSERVICEFILE

Look at
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/libpq-pgservice.html

Format is ".INI". **Parameters are connection parameters.**
Example:

```
# this is a comment in my service file
[a_service]
host=dbserver.loc
port=5432
dbname=thedbname
user=thebest
password=bho
application_name=ifyoulike

# Here is another service
[another_service]
host=etc
port=etc
```

Access via psql:

`psql service=a_service`

Access via psycopg2:

`db = psycopg2.connect('service=a_service')`

Access via sqlalchemy:

`eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql:///?service=another_service')`

Answer (score -7):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint

def main():
    conn_string = "host='127.0.0.1' dbname='yourdatabsename'  user='yourusername' password='yourpassword'"
print "Connecting to database\n ->%s" % (conn_string)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename")


records = cursor.fetchall()
pprint.pprint(records)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: The question clearly states that the password should not be specified in the code and this example does exactly the opposite.